# All components are showing while redirecting with withRouter()

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-router-v4

I am new to Reactjs and I'm understanding routing. Here I have used [`withRouter()`](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/withRouter.md) to redirect programmatically.

The flow of this what I think should be: `constructor->Willmount->render`, but currently the flow is `constructor->render->willMount->render`.

When I'm executing this code what happens is that first component at `/login` is showing, and after that Header component is showing (login component up and header after it)

```
class Main extends Component {

constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = { userInfo: ''};
}


 async componentDidMount() {

  let user = await apiGateway.getUserInfo();
   console.log(' did Mount1');
    if(user == null){
      console.log('Redirect');
      this.props.history.push('/login');
    }else{
      console.log('data');
      this.setState({ userInfo : user.data });
    }

}

render() {
    const { authenticate, userInfo, onlineUser } = this.state;
    console.log('main component');
      return (
        <div className='Main'>
          <div className='Main-header'>
           <Header userInfo = {userInfo}/>
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    }

}

export default withRouter(Main);
```

Answer (score 1):

Its bad practice to make api calls in `componentWillMount`.
You cannot expect the api call to receive results in time the  component will `render`.
Always make api calls in `componentDidMount`.

class Main extends Component {

```
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = { userInfo: ''};
    }


     async componentDidMount() {

      let user = await apiGateway.getUserInfo();
       console.log(' did Mount1');
        if(user == null){
          console.log('Redirect');
          this.props.history.push('/login');
        }else{
          console.log('data');
          this.setState({ userInfo : user.data });
        }

    }

    render() {
        const { authenticate, userInfo, onlineUser } = this.state;
        console.log('main component');
          return (
            <div className='Main'>
              <div className='Main-header'>
               <Header userInfo = {userInfo}/>
              </div>
            </div>
          );
        }

   }
```

Comment: okay i will take care of it .. but code is still not executing properly